# UIPopoverController loses position

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm currently porting an app to iOS 7 and I'm seeing a new and odd behaviour related with the UIPopoverController. Basically I have a UIPopoverController that contains a UINavigationController. Within the Navigation Controller I'm pushing and popping view controllers. I've seen an issue where popping a view controller while the keyboard is visible causes the UIPopoverController to lose it's anchor (Where it's arrow is pointing too). It also moves to the lower right of the screen. I've also seen the same behaviour if I have the keyboard present and I split it.

Some notes:

- My toolbar is placed at the bottom of the screen.
- I'm using

  ```
  [_popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
  ```
- I've made sure that the sender is a valid UIBarButtonItem.
- Also I get this warning in the console when this happens:

  > 2014-03-06 14:58:20.557 ACCMobile[5428:707] -[UIPopoverController
  >       presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: 
  >       the rect passed in to this method must have non-zero width and height. 
  >       This will be an exception in a future release.

I'm wondering if there's some type of behaviour that I'm not understanding when the keyboard slides in and out?

Comment: Try using `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` instead of `-Any`. I know it does solve some known issues with popovers. The exception you see is likely a bug of the implementation, as they call `presentPopoverFromRect:` internally, passing the bar item view params. If they lost the bar item, the rect could be coming as {0,0,0,0} and causing the log line.

Comment: I've seen a few people that changed the ArrowDirection and it solved the issue. This parameter doesn't seem to make a difference in my case. I've used `Any,Up,Down,Up|Down` and nothing works. I'm wondering at this point if I should try and use `presentPopoverFromRect:` instead of `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:`

Comment: You could, but keep in mind the following: You don't have access to the private bar item views (without subview tinkering) and you will have to manage popover movement after rotation. It's not that hard, just more work to do.

Comment: I tried loading my current popover around a static CGRect for now to isolate it and it does the same thing using both methods. I've just spent some time writing a prototype app to reproduce it in a simpler environment and I can't seem to reproduce the behaviour... I'm at a loss right now.